# Django filter multiple fields with same choices

Tags: django, django-filters

I have a model that looks like this:

```
field_1 = models.IntegerField(choices=FIELD_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
field_2 = models.IntegerField(choices=FIELD_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
```

I would like to create a filter with django_filters, to combine these 2 separate fields into 1 single ChoiceFilter. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify method which will be used to filter on custom field:

```
class YouFilter(FilterSet):
    new_field = ChoiceFilter(method='filter_new_field', choices=FIELD_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'new_field')

    def filter_new_field(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(
            field_1=value,
            field_1=value
        )
```